# Remove subdirectory from URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following URL:
http://example.org/search/search

Using htaccess, I need to remove the first /search from the URL so that the URL is:
http://example.org/search

For the life of me I can't figure out how.
Here's the relevant section of my htaccess file

```
# Remove www from URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove the need for the php file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.org/$1 [R=302,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# Remove index from home URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how the rules that you have ever worked. You have some duplicate rules and redirects that interfere with routing. Put all your redirects in the same place, and make sure you use the `-f` check before you add the php extension:

```
# Remove www from URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.org/$1 [R=302,L]

# Remove index from home URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*)index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove the search folder:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+search/search
RewriteRule ^search/search(.*)$ /search$1 [L,R=301]

# Add the search folder back
RewriteCond $1 !^/search
RewriteRule ^search(.*)$ /search/search$1 [L]

# Add the extension back on if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```